# How to set many tables in the same page with LaTeX

Tags: latex

i'm new to latex and i just want to put 3 tables in the same page, one above the other.
The size i think it's fine, the only problem is that tables are divided by some text from the next chapter..
Any tips?

my code is something like this:

```
....

\newpage

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table 1}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
% table 1
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table 2}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
% table 2
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table 3}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
% table 3
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of floats that can be on a page is governed by a number of parameters (see [How to influence the position of float environments like `figure` and `table` in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)):

> There are four counters that control how many floats can go into areas:
>
> - `totalnumber` (default 3) is the maximum number of floats on a text (!) page
> - `topnumber` (default 2) is the maximum number of floats in the top area
> - `bottomnumber` (default 1) is the maximum number of floats in the bottom area
> - `dbltopnumber` (default 2) is the maximum number of full sized floats in two-column mode going above the text columns.
>
> The size of the areas are controlled through parameters (changed with `\renewcommand`) that define the maximum (or minimum) size of the area, expressed as a fraction of the page height:
>
> - `\topfraction` (default 0.7) maximum size of the top area
> - `\bottomfraction` (default 0.3) maximum size of the bottom area
> - `\dbltopfraction` (default 0.7) maximum size of the top area for double-column floats
> - `\textfraction` (default 0.2) *minimum* size of the text area, i.e., the area that must *not* be occupied by floats

Depending on the actual document, you may need to adjust the counters (or fractions) to allow more content to fit on the page. Alternatively, avoid the `figure`s from floating (since you want to have a specific placement) by adding the [`float` package](//ctan.org/pkg/float) and using the `[H]` "float"/placement specifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
....

\newpage

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table 1}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
% table 1
\end{tabular}


\centering
\caption{Table 2}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
% table 2
\end{tabular}


\centering
\caption{Table 3}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
% table 3
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

...
```

Comment: one `\centering` is enough